# NPM install is not working [code 128]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

NPM is not working it's giving permission denied error. Here is the full log:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/jonschlinkert/resolve-file.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-8b5c9e7d
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-8b5c9e7d': Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T06_46_34_324Z-debug.log
root@ip-172-31-15-60:/var/www/html/itracker# npm install request
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/jonschlinkert/resolve-file.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-77c3de2c
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-77c3de2c': Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T06_47_05_916Z-debug.log
```

**What i tried:**

- completely removed node and NPM and installed.

  sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm

by following the answer from here: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

**Note:**

I tried to install globally is working. But installing locally is not working.
I tried both **sudo and normal** user.

Comment: try sudo npm install

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I'm already sudo user. That's why I didn't care about added sudo at the beginning. But I tried worked!

Comment: you tried what ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi sudo npm install

Comment: does the problem resolved now ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi yes

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Put it as a answer, this may help someone.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `sudo npm install` even if you are working on sudo user

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest npm

```
npm install -g npm
```